# Start from the top of the layout / activity

Tags: java, android

I'm working on android app, and I have the screen where the user can register and put the information about himself. it's a long screen where the user needs to scroll down to complete it. When I'm testing it with the emulator, the courser always goes to the last `EditText` box which is `android:id="@+id/tbJoinBio`.

I want the courser to start from the top box `android:id="@+id/tbJoinUsername`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/light_green" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.29" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="950dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="303dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                    android:text="@string/join_welcome" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblLoginUsername"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:text="@string/login_label_username"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinUsername"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblLoginUsername"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblLoginUsername"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="user"
                    android:inputType="text" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblLoginPassword"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tbJoinUsername"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbJoinUsername"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="@string/login_label_password"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinPassword"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblLoginPassword"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblLoginPassword"
                    android:text="password"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPassword" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbJoinPassword"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:text="@string/join_password_confirm"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinPassword2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView01"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:text="password" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbJoinPassword2"
                    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
                    android:text="@string/join_email"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinEmail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/TextView02"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="user@user.com"
                    android:inputType="text" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:text="@string/join_button_register" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbJoinEmail"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="First Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinFirstName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblFirstName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:text="User"
                    android:inputType="text" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblMiddleName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/lblFirstName"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lblFirstName"
                    android:text="MI"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinMiddleName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="M"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lblMiddleName"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblMiddleName"
                    android:ems="2"
                    android:inputType="text" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>                

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblLastName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbJoinFirstName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="Last Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinLastName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblLastName"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lbldob"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbJoinLastName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="DOB (MMDDYYYY)"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoindob"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="10221955"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lbldob"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" >

                    <requestFocus />

                </EditText>      

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblStreetAddr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbJoindob"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="Street Address"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinStreetAddr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="United States"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblStreetAddr"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" >

                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText> 

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblPhoneNum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbJoinStreetAddr"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="Phone Number"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinPhoneNum"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2155555555"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblPhoneNum"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" >

                    <requestFocus />

                </EditText>      


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblBio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tbJoinPhoneNum"
                    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                    android:text="About you"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/tbJoinBio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="I'm awesome"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lblBio"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:inputType="text" >

                    <requestFocus />

                </EditText>                
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the tags

```
<requestFocus />
```

Comment: Your welcome, you should only put this tag where you want it.

Answer (score 2):

Move the `<requestFocus/>` tag to the `android:id="@+id/tbJoinUsername` element.